# How to set mean pixels for feedforward? caffe

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe, feed-forward

I want to finetune  VGG19 and it is working good. While training I am subtracting the mean pixels as

```
name: "VGG_ILSVRC_19_layer"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
 transform_param {
    mean_value: 104
    mean_value: 117
    mean_value: 123
    mirror: false
 }
 data_param {
    source: "examples/VGG_finetune/train_lmdb"
    batch_size: 8
    backend: LMDB
  }
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
}
```

Now I need to feedforward through my finetuned network. If I look at [this](https://gist.github.com/ksimonyan/3785162f95cd2d5fee77#file-readme-md)
they are not specifying mean pixel value in deploy file.

**Question:**
How can I provide my network mean pixel value while feedforwarding?
My code for feedforward(loading network) is

```
net = caffe.Classifier(model_prototxt, model_trained,
                           mean=[104,117,123],
                           channel_swap=(2,1,0),
                           raw_scale=255,
                           image_dims=(224, 224))
```

Now I am not sure whether `mean=(104,117,123)` work or not because when I viewed source code of `classifier` then I came to know through comments in code that it only takes `ndarray` otherwise it give error.
How can I subtract mean pixels from input image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can specify your `mean` as `ndarray` simply by

```
net = caffe.Classifier(model_prototxt, model_trained,
                       mean=NP.array( [104, 117, 123], dtype='f4'),
                       channel_swap=(2,1,0),
                       raw_scale=255,
                       image_dims=(224, 224))
```

Comment: Thanks Shai for helping me again.